# Common Lisp: Getting the documentation string of a macro

Tags: macros, documentation, common-lisp

In SBCL, I can get the documentation string for a function with something like this:

```
(documentation #'mapcar t)
```

However, I don't understand how to get the documentation string for a macro.  For example, given the macro:

```
(defmacro with-lines-in-file ((line filename) &body body)
  "Runs body for each line in the file specified by filename."
  (let ((file (gensym)))
    `(with-open-file (,file ,filename)
      (do ((,line (read-line ,file nil) (read-line ,file nil)))
          ((null ,line) nil)
        ,@body))))
```

I'm not able to retrieve the documentation string.  I don't understand the  CLHS.  As you can see below, the CLHS worked great for obtaining the documentation string for a function.

```
documentation (x function) (doc-type (eql 't))
```

However, the bit for obtaining the documentation string from a macro doesn't seem to work for me:

```
documentation (x symbol) (doc-type (eql 'compiler-macro))
```

In the context of my macro, I'm interpreting the above CLHS bit to mean this:

```
(documentation 'with-lines-in-file 'compiler-macro)
```

But that call returns NIL.

I'm trying to build a function that creates the README.md file for the Common Lisp packages that I plan to share on GitHub.  Here's an example: https://github.com/macnod/dc-utilities.  I've written a post about this here: https://donnieknows.com/documenting-common-lisp-for-github/.

Comment: Compiler macros are a different thing from regular macros. You should get the macro docstring with `(documentation ... 'function)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard says for the Common Lisp function [documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_docume.htm#documentation):

**function** *If x is a function name, returns the documentation string of the function, macro, or special operator whose name is x.*

The three operator types one can retrieve documentation from, with the argument `function` are thus:

- function
- macro
- special operator

Remember, in Common Lisp an operator can only be one of those at a time.

Example

```
CL-USER> (defmacro foomacro () "foo macro" '(foo))
FOOMACRO
CL-USER> (documentation 'foomacro 'function)
"foo macro"
```

Macros are not *compiler macros*. Those are defined by [DEFINE-COMPILER-MACRO](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_define.htm#define-compiler-macro).

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  I've learned that I need to read the docs more carefully.  I apologize for the time suck.