# Common Lisp - Get docstring from methods AND functions?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

This is a follow up to this previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948271/common-lisp-getting-the-documentation-string-of-a-macro/) about the documentation function, which apparently deserved its own post.

Is there a way to dynamically get the docstring of either a function/macro OR a method in SBCL?

So far (documentation function-name 'function) gets me the docstring for regular functions (and I assume macros as well), but not methods.
I tried 'method, 'standard-method and even 't but they don't seem to work.

My problem is that the environment I work with (in a visual programming interface based on Lisp) is filled with little engines that can be either functions or methods and I don't know how to differentiate them. I just need users to be able to get the docstring quickly for any given symbol (or tool) in the library, no matter its type, if it exists of course.

Thanks !

Julien

Comment: [`DESCRIBE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_descri.htm) would be more appropriate if you just want to view the documentation. `DOCUMENTATION` is only needed if you want to process the string somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Symbols name functions, including macros and generic-functions, but not methods. In order to uniquely identify a method, you need to know the generic-function and all  the applicable modifiers and specializers.

For example, [`PRINT-OBJECT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) names a generic function, but is not sufficient to refer to a specific methods. You can however iterate over all methods specializing a generic function and manipulate their documentation: instead of passing a name to [`DOCUMENTATION`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_docume.htm), you give the function  object and `T`. In order to do this portably, use [*closer-mop*](https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop):

```
(ql:quickload :closer-mop)
```

For example:

```
(lambda (generic-function)
  (map 'list
       (lambda (method) (documentation method t))
       (closer-mop:generic-function-methods generic-function)))
=> #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (GENERIC-FUNCTION)) {1001BBCD3B}>
```

Let's try it:

```
CL-USER> (funcall * #'documentation)
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

Oops.

```
CL-USER> (defmethod documentation ((test (eql :test)) _) 
             "Test documentation" 
           "Returned value")
...
CL-USER> (documentation :test t)
"Returned value"

CL-USER> (funcall *** #'documentation)
("Test documentation" NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```